# Better printout of the questions

Tags: feature-request, printing

I, as a student, come across a lot a questions on the network while studying and I print them so that I can refer to the question when I revise my topics for finals or any other paper but the printouts are generally very bad.

The text takes up very little space left aligned which wastes quite a bit of paper as per my very scientific investigation only 15.8% of the paper is taken up by text[image]

Pictures get resized and are not readable at all  [image]

Mathjax is sized perfectly for some reason[image]